# Converting Cursor statement from SQL Server to Oracle doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, oracle, cursor

I use a cursor to move all the records from the table CUT_CALENDAR to SD_CALENDAR (migration of Calendars). I use the following cursor on Sql Server for this:

```
DECLARE @sdCalendarId NUMERIC(20)
DECLARE @calendarTypId NUMERIC(5)
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(35)
DECLARE @description NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ptyId NUMERIC(20)
DECLARE @lockCode NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @dataOwnerId NUMERIC(20)
DECLARE @cntId NUMERIC(20)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysMonday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysTuesday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysWednesday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysThursday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysFriday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysSaturday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @nonBusinessDaysSunday CHAR(1)
DECLARE @ccyId NUMERIC(20)
DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @version NUMERIC(10)
DECLARE @seal VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @lstUpdTs DATETIME



DECLARE cursorCutoffCalendar CURSOR FOR
  SELECT ID, NAME, CALENDAR_TYP_ID,DESCRIPTION,'Y',PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS
  FROM CUT_CALENDAR
  WHERE ID != 1

OPEN cursorCutoffCalendar
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCutoffCalendar INTO @sdCalendarId, @calendarTypId, @name, @description, @ptyId, @lockCode, @dataOwnerId, @cntId, @nonBusinessDaysMonday, @nonBusinessDaysTuesday, @nonBusinessDaysWednesday, @nonBusinessDaysThursday, @nonBusinessDaysFriday, @nonBusinessDaysSaturday, @nonBusinessDaysSunday, @nonBusinessDaysMonday, @ccyId, @code, @version, @seal, @lstUpdTs
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sdCalendarId = COALESCE(MAX(ID),1) FROM SD_CALENDAR

    SET @sdCalendarId = @sdCalendarId + 1

    INSERT INTO SD_CALENDAR (ID, NAME, CALENDAR_ROLE_ID,DESCRIPTION,USE_IN_CUTOFF,PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS)
    VALUES(@sdCalendarId, @name, @calendarTypId,@description,'Y',@ptyId,@lockCode,@dataOwnerId,@cntId,@nonBusinessDaysMonday,@nonBusinessDaysTuesday,@nonBusinessDaysWednesday,@nonBusinessDaysThursday,@nonBusinessDaysFriday,@nonBusinessDaysSaturday,@nonBusinessDaysSunday,@ccyId,@code,@version,@seal,@lstUpdTs)
END
CLOSE cursorCutoffCalendar
DEALLOCATE cursorCutoffCalendar
GO
```

Because I also want to support the Oracle architecture, I tried to convert this SqlServer cursor to the following Oracle cursor:

```
    DECLARE v_sdCalendarId NUMERIC(20);
     v_calendarTypId NUMERIC(5);
     v_name VARCHAR2(35);
     v_description VARCHAR2(255);
     v_ptyId NUMERIC(20);
     v_lockCode VARCHAR2(20);
     v_dataOwnerId NUMERIC(20);
     v_cntId NUMERIC(20);
     v_nonBusinessDaysMonday CHAR(1);
     v_nonBusinessDaysTuesday CHAR(1);
     v_nonBusinessDaysWednesday CHAR(1);
     v_nonBusinessDaysThursday CHAR(1);
     v_nonBusinessDaysFriday CHAR(1);
     v_nonBusinessDaysSaturday CHAR(1);
     v_nonBusinessDaysSunday CHAR(1);
     v_ccyId NUMERIC(20);
     v_code VARCHAR2(30);
     v_version NUMERIC(10);
     v_seal VARCHAR(255);
     v_lstUpdTs DATE;
    CURSOR cursorCutoffCalendar IS
        SELECT ID, NAME, CALENDAR_TYP_ID,DESCRIPTION,'Y',PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS
        FROM CUT_CALENDAR
        WHERE ID != 1;

 BEGIN
    FOR calendar IN cursorCutoffCalendar
    LOOP
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID),1) into v_sdCalendarId from SD_CALENDAR;

                    INSERT INTO SD_CALENDAR (ID, NAME, CALENDAR_ROLE_ID,DESCRIPTION,USE_IN_CUTOFF,PTY_ID,LOCK_CODE,DATA_OWNER_ID,CNT_ID,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_MONDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_TUESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_WEDNESDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_THURSDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_FRIDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SATURDAY,NON_BUSINESS_DAYS_SUNDAY,CCY_ID,CODE,VERSION,SEAL,LST_UPD_TS)
                    VALUES(v_sdCalendarId, v_name, v_calendarTypId,v_description,'Y',v_ptyId,v_lockCode,v_dataOwnerId,v_cntId,v_nonBusinessDaysMonday,v_nonBusinessDaysTuesday,v_nonBusinessDaysWednesday,v_nonBusinessDaysThursday,v_nonBusinessDaysFriday,v_nonBusinessDaysSaturday,v_nonBusinessDaysSunday,v_ccyId,v_code,v_version,v_seal,v_lstUpdTs);
    END LOOP;
CLOSE cursorCutoffCalendar;

END;
/
```

> ORA-01001: invalid cursor ORA-06512: at line 34

What is wrong in my oracle cursor script?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with your procedure:

1. You're fetching a cursor, but you're not storing the values anywhere. This is the cause of your error. You need to fetch the values into either a cursor rowtype variable or individual variables.
2. If you absolutely have to do a loop through a cursor, it's far easier to use a CURSOR FOR LOOP.
3. You're using max(val) + 1 to populate a (presumably) unique id column. That's not something you should do - especially if there are other concurrent transactions. Instead, you should use a sequence, eg:

.

```
create sequence sd_calendar_seq
  START WITH 261 -- something that's higher than the max id of sd_calendar
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;
```

4. You don't need a cursor for loop at all - in fact, that's the slow way of doing it. You could just use a single insert statement to do all the work in one fell swoop:

.

```
insert into sd_calendar (id,
                         name,
                         calendar_role_id,
                         description,
                         use_in_cutoff,
                         pty_id,
                         lock_code,
                         data_owner_id,
                         cnt_id,
                         non_business_days_monday,
                         non_business_days_tuesday,
                         non_business_days_wednesday,
                         non_business_days_thursday,
                         non_business_days_friday,
                         non_business_days_saturday,
                         non_business_days_sunday,
                         ccy_id,
                         code,
                         version,
                         seal,
                         lst_upd_ts)
  SELECT sd_calendar_seq.nextval,
         name,
         calendar_typ_id,
         description,
         'Y',
         pty_id,
         lock_code,
         data_owner_id,
         cnt_id,
         non_business_days_monday,
         non_business_days_tuesday,
         non_business_days_wednesday,
         non_business_days_thursday,
         non_business_days_friday,
         non_business_days_saturday,
         non_business_days_sunday,
         ccy_id,
         code,
         version,
         seal,
         lst_upd_ts
  from   cut_calendar
  where  id != 1;
```

---

Looking at your updated code, there are some additional issues:

1. Your syntax for selecting into a variable is incorrect. Instead, it should be: `select coalesce(max(id),1) into v_sdcalendarid from sd_calendar;`
2. Your syntax for setting the value of a variable is incorrect. It should be `v_sdcalendarid := v_sdcalendarid + 1;`
3. Now that you've defined your cursor record (`calendar`), you don't need all the individual variables. Also, you need to change the values being inserted to reference the record fields.
4. When you use a cursor for loop, you don't need to explicitly open or close the cursor.

That means your code should look something like:

```
declare
  v_sdcalendarid numeric (20);

  cursor cursorcutoffcalendar
  is
    select id,
           name,
           calendar_typ_id,
           description,
           'Y' use_in_cutoff,
           pty_id,
           lock_code,
           data_owner_id,
           cnt_id,
           non_business_days_monday,
           non_business_days_tuesday,
           non_business_days_wednesday,
           non_business_days_thursday,
           non_business_days_friday,
           non_business_days_saturday,
           non_business_days_sunday,
           ccy_id,
           code,
           version,
           seal,
           lst_upd_ts
    from   cut_calendar
    where  id != 1;
begin
  for calendar in cursorcutoffcalendar
  loop
    select coalesce (max (id), 1)
    into   v_sdcalendarid
    from   sd_calendar;

    v_sdcalendarid := v_sdcalendarid + 1;

    insert into sd_calendar (id,
                             name,
                             calendar_role_id,
                             description,
                             use_in_cutoff,
                             pty_id,
                             lock_code,
                             data_owner_id,
                             cnt_id,
                             non_business_days_monday,
                             non_business_days_tuesday,
                             non_business_days_wednesday,
                             non_business_days_thursday,
                             non_business_days_friday,
                             non_business_days_saturday,
                             non_business_days_sunday,
                             ccy_id,
                             code,
                             version,
                             seal,
                             lst_upd_ts)
    values      (v_sdcalendarid,
                 calendar.name,
                 calendar.calendartypid,
                 calendar.description,
                 calendar.use_in_cutoff,
                 calendar.ptyid,
                 calendar.lockcode,
                 calendar.dataownerid,
                 calendar.cntid,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdaysmonday,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdaystuesday,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdayswednesday,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdaysthursday,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdaysfriday,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdayssaturday,
                 calendar.nonbusinessdayssunday,
                 calendar.ccyid,
                 calendar.code,
                 calendar.version,
                 calendar.seal,
                 calendar.lstupdts);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

However, I would **HIGHLY** recommend two things here:

1. Use a sequence to generate the id values
2. Do this in a single insert statement, like I showed above.

If you can't use a sequence for whatever reason (why not?) you could still do something like the following:

```
insert into sd_calendar (id,
                         name,
                         calendar_role_id,
                         description,
                         use_in_cutoff,
                         pty_id,
                         lock_code,
                         data_owner_id,
                         cnt_id,
                         non_business_days_monday,
                         non_business_days_tuesday,
                         non_business_days_wednesday,
                         non_business_days_thursday,
                         non_business_days_friday,
                         non_business_days_saturday,
                         non_business_days_sunday,
                         ccy_id,
                         code,
                         version,
                         seal,
                         lst_upd_ts)
  select (select coalesce (max (id), 1) from sd_calendar) + rownum id,
         name,
         calendar_typ_id,
         description,
         'Y',
         pty_id,
         lock_code,
         data_owner_id,
         cnt_id,
         non_business_days_monday,
         non_business_days_tuesday,
         non_business_days_wednesday,
         non_business_days_thursday,
         non_business_days_friday,
         non_business_days_saturday,
         non_business_days_sunday,
         ccy_id,
         code,
         version,
         seal,
         lst_upd_ts
  from   cut_calendar
  where  id != 1;
```

The reason why I recommend the single sql statement approach is that it's easier to maintain (much less code!), easier to test (you can run the SQL statement on its own to see what rows will get inserted) and it'll be faster than the corresponding loop round a cursor. This is because relational databases are very good at processing large sets of data - it's what they're designed to do.

However, when you loop round a cursor (and do DML based on the cursor), what you're doing is:

1. From the PL/SQL engine, you make a call to the SQL engine to fetch a row.
2. Then you go back to the PL/SQL engine to do something with the results.
3. Then you go back to the SQL engine to run the DML statement.
4. Then it's back to the PL/SQL engine to fetch the next row
5. repeat steps 2-4 until no more rows are found.

That's an awful lot of context switching. Why not avoid that altogether by using a single DML statement that processes the whole set of data in bulk. You can even embed that statement in PL/SQL if you like!

Comment: I encountered again against a new problem, I've updated my answer, can you check it one more time?

Comment: @Boerejef from my answer above: `4. When you use a cursor for loop, you don't need to explicitly open or close the cursor.`... so, remove the close cursor statement. Out of curiosity, why are you still persisting with a cursor-for-loop approach and not going with a single insert statement?